# top 1 date foreach date

Tags: sql, foreach, sybase

I have this structure

```
table idc (numId,idInt, IdAffiliate)
table glob (idInt, IdAtt)
table gratt(IdAtt, dtRomp)
Table update(IdAffiliate, dateUpdate)
```

making this select statement will give me this :

```
SELECT
    NumId, 
    dateUpdate, 
    DtRomp,
    Idc.IdFiliale 
FROM Idc inner join glob on glob .IdInt = Idc.IdInt  
         inner join Grat on Glob.IdAtt = Grat.IdAtt   
         inner join update on update.IdAffiliate = Idc.IdAffiliate
where NumId = 9976666
```

will give me this :

```
NumId   DtUpdate              DtRomp            filiale
9976666 01/05/2005            11/07/2006        27
9976666 01/05/2005            03/07/2008        27
9976666 01/05/2005            24/06/2010        27
9976666 01/05/2006            11/07/2006        27
9976666 01/05/2006              03/07/2008      27
9976666 01/05/2006            24/06/2010        27
```

I m trying to do this :
to select the most close dtUpdqte to DtRomp and that is inferior to it

Kindest regards

I have been trying but but with no solution yet.

Comment: What engine and version?

Comment: From the `top 1` in the title, I'd guess SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with this!!!!!

```
SELECT
NumId, 
dateUpdate, 
DtRomp,
Idc.IdFiliale 
FROM Idc inner join glob on glob .IdInt = Idc.IdInt  
         inner join Grat on Glob.IdAtt = Grat.IdAtt   
         inner join update on update.IdAffiliate = Idc.IdAffiliate
where NumId = 9976666
and datediff(day,dateUpdate,DtRomp) = (
                                         SELECT
                                         min(datediff(day,dateUpdate,DtRomp))
                                         FROM Idc ainner join glob b on a.IdInt = c.IdInt  
                                         inner join Grat con b.IdAtt = c.IdAtt   
                                         inner join update d on d.IdAffiliate = Idc.IdAffiliate
                                         where NumId = 9976666 and Idc.IdAffiliate = a.IdAffiliate and Grat.DtRompu = c.DtRompu and Grat.DtRompu>DtDebValidite

                                      )
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select NumId, dateUpdate, DtRomp, Idc.IdFiliale
from (SELECT NumId, dateUpdate, DtRomp, Idc.IdFiliale,
             row_number() over (partition by NumID, DTRomp order by DTRomp desc) as seqnum
      FROM Idc inner join glob on glob .IdInt = Idc.IdInt  
               inner join Grat on Glob.IdAtt = Grat.IdAtt   
               inner join update on update.IdAffiliate = Idc.IdAffiliate
      where NumId = 9976666 and dateUpdate < DTRomp
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Partitioning by dateUpdate can't be right if you're looking for the latest dateUpdate

Comment: @user2583029 . . . Sybase has supported `row_number()` for a long time.  Are you using a very old version?  Does your version support CTEs (the `with` statement)?

Comment: version = 15.0.3, I don't know if this supports CTE or Partition

Comment: @GordonLinoff OP's sybase engine probably is ASE. `row_number` function is valid for IQ and maybe for ASA.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `datediff` function as below:

```
SELECT
    NumId, 
    dateUpdate, 
    DtRomp,
    Idc.IdFiliale 
FROM Idc inner join glob on glob .IdInt = Idc.IdInt  
         inner join Grat on Glob.IdAtt = Grat.IdAtt   
         inner join update on update.IdAffiliate = Idc.IdAffiliate
where NumId = 9976666
and datediff(day,dateUpdate,DtRomp) = (
                                         SELECT
                                         min(datediff(day,dateUpdate,DtRomp))
                                         FROM Idc inner join glob on glob .IdInt = Idc.IdInt  
                                         inner join Grat on Glob.IdAtt = Grat.IdAtt   
                                         inner join update on update.IdAffiliate = Idc.IdAffiliate
                                         where NumId = 9976666

                                      )
```

[More information about datediff()](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks179.htm).

Comment: NumId DtUpdate DtRomp IdFiliale 9976666 01/05/2006 00:00:00 17/07/2002 00:00:00 27

Comment: this what it returned to me, The lines i m trying to keeps will be the last 3 ones actually, I m looking at the logic to know if I can do somthing. thank you for your help

Comment: 9976666 01/05/2006            11/07/2006        27
9976666 01/05/2006              03/07/2008      27
9976666 01/05/2006            24/06/2010        27